# Not able to launch Eclipse RCP product in Eclipse Neon which was built on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Problem in launching/running RCP application built on Eclipse indigo in Eclipse Neon. Not able to resolve dependencies in the product. what might be the problem?

I have added all the required pugins in the Plugins folder of Eclipse neon. Even though I am not able to resolve the dependencies in RCP product.

When I'm validating, its not validating. it shows as below,

> com.ibm.team.fulltext.common missing constarint:required bundle:org.apache.lucene2. org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt missing constarint:required capability:osgi.extender; filter="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.2)(!(version>=2.0)))"

Is that plugins is not compatible with Eclipse Neon?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What exactly is happening? What messages are you getting?

Comment: Edit you question to provide more information

Comment: when i'm validating, its not validating. it shows as below, com.ibm.team.fulltext.common missing constarint:required bundle:org.apache.lucene2. org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt missing constarint:required capability:osgi.extender; filter="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.2)(!(version>=2.0)))"